# Can pip install first search wheel in a specified local dir and then the pypi?

Tags: python, pip

Can pip install first search wheel in a specified local dir and then the pypi?

If the specified local dir doesn't contain the want wheel, it will search the pypi.

Especially when use `pip install -r requirements.txt` command.

Comment: I know use `--no-index` together with  `--find-links=file:///the/local/dir` can search local dir to install the wheels. But in this situation, it can only search wheels in the specified local dir when using `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 4):

Sure is. Add

```
--find-links some/local/directory/with/wheels
```

to the command line.

If you also add `--no-index`, it won't consult the online index.

If that doesn't work for you, try

```
--index-url=/some/local/directory --extra-index-url=https://pypi.org/simple
```

instead.

Comment: I test if only use `--find-links`, it will search pypi first.

Comment: also not work, with --index-url=/some/local/directory will raise pip ignore warning. @AKX

Comment: This won't work, for --extra-index man pages stats  **Extra URLs of package indexes to use in addition to --index-url.** It says IN ADDITION to --index-url, and I think we can' t point --index-url to a file directory.

Comment: As yuexia writes, if you want it to search your folder first, before searching pypi, you must write `--no-index` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is not intended for such usage. If you wanna use said local dir as a cache `pip` doesn't really use it because `pip` has its own cache. `pip` fills the cache during installation — it caches downloaded or built wheel files so the next time you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` with the same `requirements.txt` it uses wheels from the cache. But `pip` anyway contacts PyPI (or any configured index URLs) to check if there are newer versions.

If you insist on using your local dir as the cache you can do it in two steps:

One — update your cache with absent wheels:

```
pip download -r requirements.txt --dest=local/dir
```

This makes `pip` to download dependencies that are not in the local dir. Wheels that are already there are not re-downloaded.

Two — install:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --find-links=local/dir --no-index
```