# How to configure pip to look for modules in a local directory first

Tags: python, pip

I have a local pip server in my company that hosts a lot of modules, some of those are outdated.

Since I don't have the ability to add/modify modules in the server, I have created a local directory and downloaded the latest versions for some modules I need.

Now I want to modify my local pip configuration `pip.conf` so that pip would firstly look for modules in my directory, and if it doesn't find any, then look up them up in the local server.

How can I achieve that? Is it possible to do so without hosting a server locally?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68116396/7976758

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cache files locally.  Useful if you would be offline.  See https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installing-from-local-packages